# What could cause neutral wires in my service panel to read 120V?

Tags: electrical, breaker-box

I have a 200 A service panel with 12 breakers. Seven of the breakers work fine.  There are 5 other lines that come in.  When I hook up the black wires to the breakers and turn them on I get a charged neutral wire. It is reading 120 V. What could be the problem?

Comment: What are you reading 120v between? Neutral from panel and ground, neutral from circuit and ground, or neutral and hot?

Comment: Also, what's on the other end of the lines?

Comment: Did you also hook up the white wires corresponding to those 5 circuits you just hooked black wires to breakers?  Or did you leave them unconnected and measure them that way, relative to ground?